# Timeframe for Iframe support on Facebook fan pages

Tags: facebook

Currently Facebook does not allow developers to use iframes on Fan Page Tabs:

"*The one exception: if you absolutely must create an application that appears as a tab on a Facebook Page, you will need to use FBML for now; tabs do not currently support iframes directly. We will be transitioning tabs to iframes later this year -- please see the developer roadmap for more details.*"
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

But according to the developer roadmap they will soon (Q4 2010):

"*We are also moving toward IFrames instead of FBML for both canvas applications and Page tabs. As a part of this process, we will be standardizing on a small set of core FBML tags that will work with both applications on Facebook and external Web pages via our JavaScript SDK, effectively eliminating the technical difference between developing an application on and off Facebook.com.
We will begin supporting IFrames for Page tabs in the next few months. Developers building canvas applications should start using IFrames immediately. By the end of this year, we will no longer allow new FBML applications to be created, so all new canvas applications and Page tabs will have to be based on IFrames and our JavaScript SDK. We will, however, continue to support existing implementations of the older authentication mechanism as well as FBML on Page tabs and applications.*"
http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap

Anyone know the status of this of have a better idea of what methods Facebook developers are using for Iframe apps on Fan Pages Tabs?

According to their logic, I should develop the canvas application as an Iframe now, but how is it supported on the Profile Tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second blurb is more up-to-date.  I think they announced these plans in the last month.  As far as I know, Facebook's current target for page tab iframe support is still Q4 2010.

For now, you'll just have to develop your application in FBML/FBJS and make it installable to Facebook Pages through the application settings.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm really trying to avoid using FBML/FBJS since we have a lot of native JS prexisting for this app. The FB tab app basically just renders the same content/ provide the same functionality of the web based app but int the FB context. Thats why an Iframe is greatly preferred so that we dont have to rewrite everything.

Comment: We prefer to use iframes too when possible, but Facebook doesn't give developers a choice when it comes to page tabs. How about a compromise? You can put a splash screen on the page tab consisting of a single image link to the canvas app.

Comment: Thx. Yeah our CEO explicitly does not want to do that (splash screen). So I am digging into FBML right now.